# <br /> not working on newly created list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, line-breaks

I have a favorites list that's populated by a click event. Even though the functionality is working the list items aren't being separated by line breaks:

> Guide to Stuff.docxTemplate 1.docxTemplate 2.docxNext
>
> Line.docxThen More.docx

I included `<br/>` in `.append()` but it didn't work. I've included line breaks with jQuery before so I'm not sure as to why it's not working now. Any thoughts?

### JS snippet:

```
function faveFunc(evt) {
    var anchor = $($(evt.target).prev().find("a")[0]).clone();
    switch($(".populate-faves").find("a:contains(" + $(anchor).text() + ")").length)
    {
      case 0:
        $(".populate-faves").append(anchor);
        break;
      default:
        $(".populate-faves > a:contains(" + $(anchor).text() + ")").remove();
        break;
    }


  }; // ------------ faveFunc

function newList() {
    let data = $($(evt.target).prev().find("a")[0]).html()
    $(".populate-faves").html("");
    $("#km-table-id tbody tr").each(function(i, el) {
      let fave = $(el).find(".checkbox-class");
      let itemText = $(el).find(data);
      if($(fave).is(":checked")) {
        // $(".populate-faves").append("<li>" + $(itemText).html() + "<br/>");
        $(".populate-faves").append("<li> <br />");
      }
    });
   console.log(newList);
}; // ----- newList()
```

### HTML:

```
...

<div id="myFave.hs-gc-header" class="faves-div">
     <p style="font-weight:bold">My Favorites:</p>

     <div class="populate-faves"></div> <!-- Where I want the list items to appear -->
</div>

...
```

### ---

### Updated code:

```
function newList() {
    let data = $(evt.target).prev().find("a").eq(0).html();
     let outputList = $(".populate-faves .ul-faves");

     $(".populate-faves").html("");

    $("#km-table-id tbody tr").each(function(i, el) {
      let fave = $(".checkbox-class", el);
      let itemText = $(data, el);

      if(fave.prop(":checked")) {
        outputList.append("<li>" + itemText.html() + "</li>" + "<br/>");
        // $(".populate-faves ul").append("<li> <br />");
      }
    });
    // console.log(newList);
  };
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="myFave.hs-gc-header" class="faves-div">
            <p style="font-weight:bold">My Favorites:</p>

            <div class="populate-faves">
              <ul class="ul-faves"></ul>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Screencap

[image]

Comment: I think you need a `<ol>` or `<ul> ` to surround the `<li>` elements

Comment: `li` without a parent `ol` or `ul` is invalid. You need to change the `.populate-faves` element to a `ul`, or place a `ul` inside it and append to that instead

Comment: And you need to close your `<li>`s using `</li>`. A much better way is to do `$('container').append($('<li>').text("bla"));` Also, don't use `<br/>`s for your linebreaks, use a block element or CSS to set the elements to `display: block`.

Comment: @ChrisG Like this? `$(".ul-faves").append($("<li>")).text($(itemText));`

Comment: `li` can also be a child of a `menu` element.  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-li-element

Comment: Which part of the screen capture is the list?

Comment: Adding a selected item to the Favorites list. The screencap shows that the list items aren't being separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added comments to the code and cleaned it up a bit.  Added a `ul` for it to append the elements to.

```js
function newList() {
  let data = $(evt.target).prev().find("a").eq(0).html(); // use eq() to avoid breaking out of the jQuery object
  let outputList = $(".populate-faves .list"); // lookup the output list once
  
  $(".populate-faves").html("");
  
  $("#km-table-id tbody tr").each(function(i, el) {
    // you can use the $(selector, context) version to avoid creating unnecessary jQuery objects
    let fave = $(".checkbox-class", el);
    let itemText = $(data, el);
    
    // if you already have the element, use prop('checked') instead of is(':checked') to access the boolean property on the element
    if(fave.prop("checked")) {
      //append the li to the list, properly closing it
      outputList.append("<li>" + itemText.html() + "</li>");
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<div id="myFave.hs-gc-header" class="faves-div">
  <p style="font-weight:bold">My Favorites:</p>

  <div class="populate-faves">
    <ul class="list"></ul> <!-- CREATED unorder list FOR OUTPUT -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Taplar, thanks for the response and the code. I made the changes you recommended but unfortunately the list items are still not separated.

Comment: Is there any way you can show an example of your issue with a runnable snippet in your question?  @Bodrov

Comment: I've tried before but haven't had any luck. I edited my post body with the updated code and a screencap.

Comment: Hey @Taplar I shifted some things around and I got it. It appeared that I wasn't using the right selector---I noticed that the selected items weren't changing to the color I set in the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You need `<ul>` or `<ol>` to use `<li>`. 
Also the `<li>` element is missing the closing tag.